# method chaining with sub-methods

Tags: javascript, methods, method-chaining

I am trying to use method chain with sub-methods.

IE: `foo("bar").do.stuff()`

The catch is `stuff()` needs to have a reference to the value of `bar("bar")`

Is there any `this.callee` or other such reference to achieve this?

Comment: Is it a fluent API you're referring to here?

Comment: Is `do` is a property or you miss spelled it for function like `..do().stuff()`?

Comment: do is a property, that's why this is a bit challenging.

Comment: @xyz as crowder said, that wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Well, you will have to provide any context yourself.

Comment: What you've asked to do is not particularly practical.  You should probably back up and explain what you're really trying to accomplish because there are probably much better ways to go than this.

Comment: @jfiend00 I am aware there are a lot of other ways to chain methods. It's purely for syntactical elegance.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any this.callee or other such reference to achieve this?

No, you'd have to have `foo` return an object with a `do` property on it, which either:

1. Make `stuff` a closure over the call to `foo`
2. Have information you want from `foo("bar")` as a property of `do`, and then reference that information in `stuff` from the `do` object via `this`, or

```js
// Closure example:
function foo1(arg) {
  return {
    do: {
      stuff: function() {
        snippet.log("The argument to foo1 was: " + arg);
      }
    }
  };
}
foo1("bar").do.stuff();

// Using the `do` object example (the `Do` constructor and prototype are just
// to highlight that `stuff` need not be a closure):
function Do(arg) {
  this.arg = arg;
}
Do.prototype.stuff = function() {
  snippet.log("The argument to foo2 was: " + this.arg);
};
function foo2(arg) {
  return {
    do: new Do(arg)
  };
}
foo2("bar").do.stuff();
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `do` , `stuff` as properties of `foo` , return arguments passed to `foo` at `stuff` , return `this` from `foo`

```js
var foo = function foo(args) {
  this.stuff = function() {
    return args
  }
  this.do = this;
  return this
}

console.log(foo("bar").do.stuff())
```