# nesting functions for jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to author a jQuery plugin such that the syntax uses a dot-notated nested function rather than requiring a parameter to be passed in?

For example:

```
$.fn.switchElement = {};

$.fn.switchElement.in = function() {
  console.log(this); // logs $.fn.switchElement as an object containing a function called 'in'
  this.attr('id'); // TypeError: this.attr is not a function (naturally; the above line shows us that it's not a jQuery object)
}
```

As the comment mentions, trying to invoke via something like (`$(selector).switchElement.in();` does not work because the reference to `this` is not what one needs for writing a jQuery plugin; namely, `this` needs to be an incoming jQuery object.

I'll be the first to admit, this is purely syntax, and the plugin would be perfectly functional accepting an "in" parameter for a `$.fn.switchElement` function instead.

That said, is there a pattern I can use to accomplish my goal?

---

[edit]

I gave one of the suggestions below a try... admittedly not fully understanding it. Here's my best attempt at understanding it:

A function that will become the plugin is defined, called "switcher" which accepts an argument. In my case, I intend to pass a jQuery object which is a target, so I call mine "$target".

Within switcher is what will be the nested function, called (for now) `switchIn()`. Because it is within the scope of `switcher`, it has access to the same `this`. I sanity check that I have a `$target` and then I append `this` (a jQuery object) to the target before returning `this` to facilitate chaining.

With the function now declared, we move it into an object arbitrarily called "inner". Within "inner", we set the function `to()`. `to()` is a function that is essentially `switchIn()` but bound with the `this` that's in scope, along with the $target).

The first setTimeout I don't fully understand still. But within it, the inner (or nest of functions) becomes the plugin called "switchElement".

At the end of `switcher`, `this` is returned, which again allows for chaining.

The next `$.fn[pluginName]` I don't understand either. Didn't I already set a plugin called "switchElement" which contains a function called "to"?

Finally is the extra interesting part. First I initialize the plugin by calling it chained to a jQuery object and passing in my target. This allows the `this` and the `$target` to be set in a closure analogy? Does this mean that $target is always going to be the target until I re-initialize?

In the provided sample code, I am also including an additional button click that shows the syntax I wish I could use, without initialization. Just `$(selector).switchElement.to($(target))`. This is all done up as a fiddle, too: http://jsfiddle.net/comrhqr4/1/

```
(function($) {

  var pluginName = "switchElement";

  var switcher = function switcher($target) {

    var switchIn = function switchIn($target) {
        console.log('invoking fn and sanity checking $target, which is ', $target);
      if ($target) {
        this.appendTo($target);
      }
      return this
    }

    var inner = {
      "to": switchIn.bind(this, $target)
    };

    setTimeout(function() {
      $.fn[pluginName] = inner
    })

    return this
  };

  $.fn[pluginName] = switcher;

    $(document).on('click', '#switchTo1', function() {
        console.log('clicked #switchTo1');
      $('#unique').switchElement($('#container1'));
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#unique').switchElement.to().css('color', 'blue');
        })
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#switchTo4', function() {
        console.log('clicked #switchTo4');
      $('#unique').switchElement.to($('#container4'));
    });

}(jQuery));
```

So, some remaining questions:

1. Is it a correct assumption that $target is now set until a re-initialization?
2. Is there any way to achieve the syntax desired in my "button 4 press"?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919441/method-chaining-with-sub-methods

Comment: This prototype pattern might help http://markdalgleish.com/2011/05/creating-highly-configurable-jquery-plugins/

Comment: Regarding my updated sample: I realize that in the end, all it's doing is something that jQuery already does (moving an item from point A to point B). In the production code, there is a placeholder and some other housekeeping involving dynamically-loaded content that makes more sense than just the above. I'm after the pattern, at which time all of those other details are easily slotted in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try utilizing `Function.prototype.bind()` , `setTimeout()` ; Note, requires initializing plugin first with call to `$(element).pluginName([args])`

```js
(function($) {
  
  var pluginName = "switchElement";
  
  var Foo = function Foo(args) {
    
    var fn = function fn(args) {
      console.log(this, this.attr("id"));
      if (args) {
        this.html(args)
      }
      return this
    }

    var inner = {
      "in": fn.bind(this, args)
    };

    setTimeout(function() {
      $.fn[pluginName] = inner
    })

    return this
  };

  $.fn[pluginName] = Foo;
  
}(jQuery));

$("body").switchElement("123");
setTimeout(function() {
  $("body").switchElement.in();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<body id="abc">
</body>
```

---

Alternatively, using `$.extend()`

```js
var switchElement = { in : function() {
    console.log(this, this.attr("id"))
  }
}
$.fn.switchElement = function() {
  return $.extend({}, this, switchElement)
};

$("body").switchElement().in()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<body id="abc"></body>
```

Comment: The second one fits my brain patterns better (ie. I can grok it) but chaining a method into the next isn't quite the nice syntax of the first. I will try wrapping my head around the first, though, since it fits my needs best!

Comment: Regarding the first one (which I'm working on wrapping my head around), why is that second call wrapped in a setTimeout? I know that setTimeout can be used to break synchronous calls, but is there a synchronous call being made that's impeding functionality? Also wrt that first one, what is the bind doing? Is that a way of making sure the nested function (once set as a jQuery plugin) has a correct "this" to work with?

Comment: @GregPettit _"Regarding the first one (which I'm working on wrapping my head around), why is that second call wrapped in a setTimeout?"_ Was not certain if expected result `.switchElement` was object , instead of anonymous function ; `setTimeout` overwrites first call to function `switchElement` with object `switchElement` from this portion of OP _"trying to invoke via something like (`$(selector).switchElement.in();`"_ . Yes, `.bind()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind sets `this` of `in` property of `inner` object

Comment: Whether I fully grok the first one or not, the second one definitely works and I will eventually get around to the first. Thanks for the time you put into this, it's appreciated! Going to learn more about `.bind()` now in general. Seems like a glaring oversight to not have learned it yet, now that I'm viewing the page you sent me to!

Comment: I couldn't help giving it an honest attempt. See edits in my original question for my attempt, a fiddle, and a (broken) test scenario of how I wish the syntax worked.